# How to separate metrics per endpoint using compojure

Tags: clojure, metrics, compojure, ring

I have enabled metrics on Compojure using metrics-clojure-ring

```
    (def app
     (->
      (wrap-defaults myapp api-defaults)
      (expose-metrics-as-json)
      (instrument)
    ))
```

but the metrics come out for all api's combined. is there a way to instrument per endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with instrumenting per endpoint? The metrics are combined on the /metrics endpoint for every endpoint. The underlying library ([Coda Hale metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/MetricRegistry.html#getMetrics--)) does that for you.

If you only want one metric on an endpoint you can select one key from the `all-metrics` hash map. E.g., create a route for `/metrics/<metric-name>` and only select the `metric-name` key from [`all-metrics`](https://github.com/sjl/metrics-clojure/blob/709d22cf0e13083d86e273b7d60602b075b9e926/metrics-clojure-core/src/metrics/utils.clj#L25) and return that. If you really want to only track one metric instead of all at once, I think you have to fork the Coda Hale code and change the implementation.

Let me know if this helps. I might not have understood your question.

Comment: sorry, i was typing in a hurry and was not clear. I would like to see separate stats for every endpoint that is defined in my defroutes. so if i have /foo and /boo, i would like to be able to see /metrics/foo and /metrics/boo. is that possible or i am missing something?

Comment: Well one way to do it is to can create a route for that with a handler that retrieves `all-metrics` and then gets the metric from it of the input parameter. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because they have different characteristics and getting overall stats for my server does not tell me where a potential issue is. breaking up metrics per endpoint is very useful when trying to see what is going on in the system, do you agree?